# Calculating complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I've been trying to calculate the complexity of the following function:

```
k=n;
while(k>0)
  g(n);
  k=k/2; {Comment: this is integer division, so 1/2=0}
end while;
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
  f(m);
```

Specifically, the complexity of the while loop.I am told that g(n)'s complexity is O(n), but I'm not sure what the complexity would be for it, and how I would work it out. I have come to realise that the complexity would not be O(0.5n^2), but am unsure how to calculate it, because of the halving each time. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your problem size is halving each iteration, how many iterations do you need to do to reach problem size of 0? I.e. given a number `n`, how many times do you need to press /2 on your (integer) calculator to reach 0?

Comment: @Karel I've tried it for a number such as 8, which gives n/2, but a number such as 20 give n/4, so I am unsure.

Comment: That number is actually called a logarithm (of base 2, as you're dividing by 2). I.e. the outer loop is repeated log(n) times, the rest should be easy :) Also see http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/581/intuition-for-logarithmic-complexity

Comment: @KarelPetranek I looked at that link, but if it is repeats log n times, how come when I use 10 as my value for n, I calculate it should run 4 times, but I get log(10) = 3.32?

Comment: You cannot run a loop 3.32 times so you always need to round the numbers up (fraction of an iteration in theory means you need to do whole iteration in practice).

Answer (score 4):

If g(n) is O(n), then your complexity is O(n*log(n))

To explain further, let us ignore g(n) for the moment

```
k = n;
while(k > 0) {
    k = k / 2;
}
```

Let say n = 1000

Then we will get the following values of k

```
Pass | k
-------------
 0   | 1000
 1   | 500
 2   | 250
 3   | 125
 4   | 62
 5   | 31
 6   | 15
 7   | 7
 8   | 3
 9   | 1
 10  | 0 (stopped)
```

log(1000) = 9.96
Note it only took 10 iterations to bring down k to zero.
This is an example of a log(n) computational complexity.

Then when you add the g(n) inside the loop, that means you add O(n) for every iteration, which gives us a grand total of O(n*log(n))

Comment: Not necessarily, it also depends on the complexity of f(m).

Comment: True, but if the complexity of f(m) is not greater than O(n*log(n)) then, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Though the while loop is indeed O(nlogn), a tighter bound is O(n). (O(N) is a subset of O(NlogN), and the while loop is actually `Theta(N)`)

Comment: @KirkBackus could you explain how you got nlogn please? I have an exam tomorrow and would really appreciate it.

Comment: @KirkBackus what if n=3? That should run 3 times, but log 3 = 1.58?

Comment: @user1899174 n=3 takes only 2 times: k=3 and k=1. k=0 does not count as a time since you don't enter the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity of the while loop is clearly `O(n log n)`. There are `log n` iterations because at the end of each iteration `k` is divided by 2. To get the number of iterations, express `n` as a power of two, say 2^x. If `2^x=n, then x = log n`. That is why the complexity of the while loop is `O(n log n)`. Don't get confused because `n` does not have be a power of 2, what implies that `log n` is not always an integer and you should write, instead of log n, `[log n]`, where `[y]` is the integer part of `y`. You can always express `[log n]` as a `c* log n`, where c is a constant, which does not change complexity of an algorithm. Therefore, you don't need `[]` function and `O(n log n)` is acceptable and correct answer.

Complexity of the for loop depends on the complexity of `f(m)`. If O(f(m)) is `O(1)`, then the loop is O(m), but if `O(f(m))` is `O(m)`, then the loop is `O(m^2)`. Because `f(m)` is also a part of the algorithm, you need to know the complexity of `f(`) if you want to be certain about complexity of the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your algorithm is:

Your first loop runs O(logn) times and each iteration has to do g(n). Thus it takes

```
O(sum{i from 0 to log(n)}{O(g(i))}).
```

The second loop runs m times. It takes:

```
O(sum{j from 0 to m}{O(f(i))})
```

Total complexity of your algorithm is:

```
O(sum{i from 0 to log(n)}{O(g(i))}) + O(sum{j from 0 to m}{O(f(i))})
```